# Django: Should sendgrid emails always be sent from Celery?

Tags: python, django, smtp, celery

I'm using `django-sendgrid-v5` and I read somewhere that it isn't good to send emails from the main webserver. Should I process emails from Celery? Or is it fine to call from the main app since I'm using an external service like Sendgrid anyways?

Comment: If you are dealing with 3rd parties make use of celery as much as possible, try to put long running code in celery.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know in which context you've read that, but I would guess it has something to do with reliability, spam and security in general.

**Short answer**: Yes, this should be fully okay as you are using an external email service.

Another option is to set up a Smart host on your webserver and let your main email server deliver it to the final recipients.

**Long answer**: Nowadays sending emails from a (web)server, which is not fully set up as an email server might be difficult in means of reliably sending emails.

Due to the massive amounts of spam and malware sent, most (or at least a lot) receiving email servers (Mail Exchangers) are trying to check if the emails they should deliver to their users, are legit.
This is done by several settings mostly on the server itself. To name only a few: [RDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup), [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail), [Greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting), etc.

In general a (web) server whos main purpose is not sending emails, does not have all these settings. This might result in difficulties to reach certain email addresses.